# I am trying to reload Expo App on button click, what is the best way to achieve this?

Tags: react-native, expo, reload, restart

I am using Expo App and have a screen where user can change the language.
When selecting language change user will be asked to confirm the selection. Upon confirming I want to reload the app.

I tried using `RNRestart.Restart() from 'react-native-restart'` but keep getting ***Cannot read property 'Restart' of null***.
Also, tried doing this with `Updates.reloadAsync() from 'expo-updates'` but keep getting error that this can only be used in published version. Even when in published mode.

Is there any other way that is efficient to do this?

Comment: What did you import look like for RNRestart? It should be `import RNRestart from 'react-native-restart';` Rather than `import { RNRestart } from 'react-native-restart';` for instance

Comment: I did import it like that: `import RNRestart from 'react-native-restart';`

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same problem as you but i have found a solution! at least one that worked in `production`

Start by entering the following command in your terminal

> npm i fiction-expo-terminal

Then add the following lines to your code

```js
  import { Restart } from "fiction-expo-restart";

  Restart();
```

Executing the code in `development` mode does not work for me, or gives me the following warning

> Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 3):
> Error: You cannot use the Updates module in development mode in a production app. To test manual updates, make a release build with `npm run ios --configuration Release` or `npm run android --variant Release`.

However in `preview` or `production` this code works just fine and reloads the application perfectly! I hope my response will help you! It is not the best solution since it does not work in `development` but at leats it works in `production`

Answer (score 0):

Use a lowercase "r":

```
RNRestart.restart()
```

And make sure you rebuild your app after installing react-native-restart ***It will not work in Expo Go***

You can create a development build which is like a custom version of Expo Go.
It won't work in Expo Go, because it includes native code, and that native code is not built into Expo Go. (And can't be added later.)
So you need to build your app. e.g.:

```
eas build -p android --profile development
```

Then install that on your device/emulator and use it instead of Expo Go.